# VB6 Form Height not setting

Tags: vb6

I am trying to change the height of a VB Form and it's remaining at the same size. All other commands to alter the form are working.

```
reportForm.cmdRun.Top = currTop - 23
reportForm.ScrollHeight = currTop + 30
reportForm.Height = currTop + 30
reportForm.Show 1
```

CurrTop currently equals 109, so the height should set to 139, but it's remaining at 570? The ScrollHeight did set to 139 as it should.

I tried reportForm.Height = 100, but the height still remained at 570.

The other problem (which is probably connected) is that when the form shows, it shows with no height at all, just the Titlebar, and I need to drag it down to show the form.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Is reportForm.MinimumHeight set to < 139? Did you try reportForm.Refresh() after setting the height?

Comment: Also isn't there reportForm.Style which needs to be set to 're-sizeable' ?

Comment: I'm not aware of any reportForm.MinimumHeight being available. Also, I just ran the debugger again, and I see that before running reportForm.Height = currTop + 30, the height was 5685, which means I am able to resize it (to 570), so that can't be the problem.

Comment: a form height of 100 is pretty small - assuming you are talking about twips.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you want the inner height of the form to be 139

you are now trying to set the total height of the form, which includes any borders and the titlebar

a quick fix would be to add (height - scaleheight) to the height you are setting

```
currTop = currTop + Height - ScaleHeight
reportForm.cmdRun.Top = currTop - 23
reportForm.ScrollHeight = currTop + 30
reportForm.Height = currTop + 30
reportForm.Show vbModal
```

Comment: (height-scaleheight) = 570 in my default settings

Comment: From all the comments, I realized my mistake. This form is actually imported from VBA, and is a 'Designers' form. There is no ScaleHeight available. The height was fine when I used 139 in VBA, as it was PIPs. In VB6, 570 is the height of the titlebar alone, which is why I can't set the height to less than 570. That is also why the form opens up with only the titlebar showing. I have to recalculate what the correct height should be set to. Thanks all.

Comment: Just googled and can do it with Screen.TwipsPerPixelX

Comment: Indeed, for normal default forms the height of the titlebar is 570 so your total height has to be larger than that ... Be careful though as there are settings which might change the height of the titlebar ... i am not familiar with a designers form, so i am not sure which settings it has and which might be changed